# RDF reading/parsing errors

Tags: rdf, jena, allegrograph

I have some RDF files which I want to import into a tripplestore(AllegroGraph), but at the first file I get a SAX parser error, stating there is an unrecognized character. After removing the line in question, everything is great. 
Then I have tried using the W3C RDF validator and Jena on the RDF with the error-line, but all I got was some warnings regarding undefined languages(absolutely nothing about the error-line). 
Could you please suggest a method(java if possible) to finding errors in RDF files?

**Edit:** The line in question is:

```
<gn:alternateName xml:lang="got">&#66352;&#66374;&#66354;&#66352;&#66365;&#66361;&#66371;&#66372;&#66352;&#66365;</gn:alternateName>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the output? What is the exact error message, and also: what does the line that produces the error look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sesame's [Rio parser](http://www.openrdf.org/doc/sesame2/api/org/openrdf/rio/package-summary.html) to do validation. There's instructions in [this blogpost](http://rivuli-development.com/further-reading/sesame-cookbook/parsing-and-writing-rdf-with-rio/) on how to work with Rio in general. For validation specifically, the trick is to create and attach a  [ParseErrorListener](http://www.openrdf.org/doc/sesame2/api/index.html?org/openrdf/rio/ParseErrorListener.html) that receives detailed warning and errors from the parser.

However, since you mention that the problem you encounter is at the level of SAX / XML, you could also just use a generic XML validator to see what's wrong. The most likely cause (but it's hard to tell without more details) is that you have an incorrectly encoded character in there somewhere.